# Architecture issue in iOS

Tags: ios, reachability

I'm using Reachability on my project to get the type of connection used, but an error has ocurred.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ContributionViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I don't know what to do... my project is for iOS 4.3 and I've never had this kind of problem before.

Thx

Comment: Have you changed anything recently? Do you have Reachability.m in your project and included in the target?

Comment: Yes I included both .m and .h files on my project and I didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include the reachability framework in your projects linked libraries ?  You can confirm by clicking on your project file on the file list and checking the build phases tab.  It should be listed in the linked library section,

Comment: Yes, my project has SystemConfiguration, Security, Mapkit, CoreLocation, UIKit, Foundation, and CoreGraphics frameworks. Did I miss something?

Comment: I see your comment above, and it is a bit ambiguous.  Did you verify that Reachability.m appears in your project's compile sources list?  It can still be in the project file list, but not be included for compile.  This is happening to me a lot lately.  The compile sources are in the same tab as the linked libraries.

Comment: That was it. Reachability.m was not in the Compile Sources list.